# Group by SQL Server (show all elements in selected group by)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm a litte confused with query, I have problem to showing table in query from SQL Server. Hope my screenshot below clearly shows my problem:

[this is my expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDytn.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
    ;WITH tb(id,id_ang,bulan)AS(
       SELECT 1,1,1 UNION
       SELECT 2,2,1 UNION
       SELECT 3,1,13 UNION
       SELECT 4,1,2
    )
    SELECT id_ang,STUFF(c.bulans,1,1,'') AS bulans FROM tb 
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT ','+LTRIM(bulan) FROM tb AS tt WHERE tt.id_ang=tb.id_ang ORDER BY ID FOR XML PATH('') ) c(bulans)
    GROUP BY id_ang,c.bulans
```

```
id_ang  bulans
1   1,13,2
2   1
```

Comment: Thanks Nolan. This is Work perfectly